# How to access S3 bucket from url using boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have been given access to an S3 bucket:

**S3 base path** : s3://folder1/folder2/*

with an IAM user account:

arn:aws:iam::< Account >:user/< username >

I've tried the following but no luck.

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id='****',
    aws_secret_access_key='****'
)
obj1 = client.get_object("folder1/folder2/*") #TypeError
obj2 = boto3.resource("folder1/folder2/*") # DataNotFoundError
```

Any help regarding this would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve an object, or list the contents of a bucket?

Answer (score 7):

s3 path consists of bucket and object in the form:

```
s3://<Bucket>/<Key>
```

You can use the following expression to split your "s3_key" into bucket and key:

```
bucket, key = s3_key.split('/',2)[-1].split('/',1)
```

So to access object from the path s3://folder1/folder2 you would do the following:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('s3')
client.get_object(Bucket='folder1', Key='folder2')
```

Comment: What if I have access to s3://folder1/folder2/folder3/* and not  s3://folder1/folder2/*?

Comment: then folder2/folder3/* is your key

Comment: The following alternatives doesn't work.
`1) Key="folder2/folder3"
2) Key="folder2/folder3/"
3) Key="folder2/folder3/*"`

However on aws-cli, the following commands works perfectly:
    `aws s3 ls s3://folder1/folder2/folder3/`

Comment: `aws s3 ls` is *listing* objects.  That's not what `get_object()` is for, so... right, that wouldn't work at all.

Comment: As sqlbot point out, get_object() are not mean for listing.  Try list_objects()
http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects   
Use "prefix" parameter to specify your folder as prefix.